# Unable to connect to webrtc server from jmeter

Tags: jmeter, webrtc

I am trying to load test WebRTC server using JMeter.

The wss URL works fine in browser, but in JMeter it is returning 400 error in WebSocketOpenConnection.

URL that I am trying to hit is :
`wss://myserver Port 3004 Path socket.io/?userId=K&EIO=3&transport=websocket`

Same URL is opening properly in Chrome.

JMeter logs:

`2022-09-08 16:27:53,195 ERROR e.l.w.WebSocketClient: Ignoring user supplied header 'Connection=Upgrade' 2022-09-08 16:27:53,195 ERROR e.l.w.WebSocketClient: Ignoring user supplied header 'Upgrade=websocket' 2022-09-08 16:27:54,320 ERROR e.l.j.w.PingPongSampler: Sampler 'WebSocket Ping/Pong': there is no connection to re-use`

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one `WebSocketOpenConnection` sampler in your Test Plan that explains a lot.

Your JMeter test [must represent a real user opening a real browser and accessing your web application with 100% accuracy](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and as a real user using a real browser you first should send a [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request to the page mainly to get some [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which may be required for successful establishing of the WebSocket connection.

Once done you need to implement [protocol upgrade mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism) to create the session.

And only then you should try to open a WebSocket connection and start sending and/or receiving messages/frames.

So you need to create the same network footprint as your browser (or other application) does and then the request will be successful. And don't forget about [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters as this `K&EIO` user ID seems to be something generated.

Comment: added like you said , screenshots are available on  https://ibb.co/YcBq46w, 
https://ibb.co/MDXM11p, https://ibb.co/mhdXJH6, https://ibb.co/m91kKcH . Still the same. Can you please once check and advice. Thanks

Comment: Your screenshots are very nice, but I can only state that there are 142 errors, it worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), maybe the answer is there.WebSocket requests and responses can be printed to the jmeter.log file if you [enable debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the plugin by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:  `<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />`. Also my recommendations are only assumptions, the answer is in your browser developer tools or in a 3rd-party sniffer tool.

Comment: Getting Headers ignored error . Updating my question with jmeter.log entries. Thanks